# Nginx alongside apache in PLESK 9.3

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, nginx

Does anyone know how to set up Nginx alongside Apache in Plesk 9.3. I want to serve my dynamic content from Apache and the static content from Nginx.

I read that there is a new configuration setting in Plesk 9.3 where you can do that, but I can't find an explanation on how to do so.

I run CentOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Apache Port Change](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PPP9/Doc/en-US/plesk-9.3-unix-advanced-administration-guide/64587.htm)" chapter of "Advanced Administration Guide" from [Plesk documentation](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/resources/) should get you started.

It's not just a simple setting which can be enabled though - requires quite a bit to reconfigure/check.

*update:* it would help if you let us know what exactly is the problem now? which step are you stuck on?

1. nginx installation
2. changing HTTP/HTTPS ports which are generated by Plesk using websrvmng, i.e. moving Apache to the back-end - described in the document
3. nginx configuration and setting up event handlers in Plesk  - see examples in the document

this [blog post](http://cnedelcu.blogspot.com/2009/09/setting-up-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-on.html) might be useful as well, without part "3. Configuring Apache" - because this can now be done automatically in Plesk 9.3.

Comment: I read that there is a configuration in the documentation, but there is no explanation on how to do it. It would be silly to post the question without checking the documentation.

Comment: sorry, but it was not clear from your question that you saw that document. I updated the answer.

Comment: I am stuck on the first part really. I don't know how to install nginx for PLESK. Or can i just follow a basic instalation tutorial.

Comment: i don't think there is some special nginx for Plesk, so you should just use nginx RPMs for CentOS, I'm pretty sure they are available either from CentOS or from nginx

Comment: After i installed the RPMs, is there a service to start? And must this service run alongside Apache, or should i disable the apache server.

Comment: nginx should use the standard initscript in /etc/init.d which you can use directly or via service command, i.e. "service nginx start" and "service nginx stop". Apache should not be disabled, since they are running with nginx at the same time, but on different ports (nginx occupies standard ports and Apache is moved to alternative ports, like 8080).